# Adding MinGW compiler to QT 5.6.0 Windows

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

I am a Total Noob at this and I know nearly nothing about this. 
I just started using Qt Creator for windows 5.6.0 and While I wrote my first "Hello World" code..

I was asked to add a kit. I searched the net for similar issues and it said that I needed a compiler for Qt. Thus, I installed MinGW from QtForums

now when go to Tools->Options->Build&Run->compiler, I can not understand how do I add it to the list.

Please help me through it?

Comment: How did you get Qt installed? if I remember correctly, at some point of the installation it asks for mingw location

Comment: @bibi 
I cant exactly remember that but I am pretty sure that It didnt ask while setting up or I might have missed that step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To just get started the easiest thing to do would be to go here:

[Link to Qt downloads page](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)

Scroll down and select `Qt 5.6.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2, 1.0 GB)` this will download the installer (its about 1 GB). Run it and choose all the default options. Then you will have Qt 5.6 with mingw and Qt Creator all setup ready to go.
Note: Before you start that its probably best to delete your current version - if you are not attached to it in any way :)

If you want to fix your current setup, then it might be longer-winded to find out what you are missing for mingw. For example you need the mingw qmake file that would be located here (using default install options):

- `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\qmake.exe`

to create your "Qt Version" part of the kit. And the actual mingw compiler, which is located here (using default install options):

- `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\g++.exe`

to create your compiler. Once you have both of these then you can put them together to create your new kit.

But to just add a compiler all you need to do is:

- Click compilers tab
- Click add and select mingw
- A new compiler is added, click it
- You will see some options below, add your compiler executable path in (like the one above for example).
- And you are done - there are some other options, but you probably don't need to use them.

**note** my paths are for qt 5.5.1 (obviously) so slightly different to 5.6 :)

**update**

Its all been moved around! - here are the new paths:

[offline-installers](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers)

[old-version-archives](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/)

Comment: What I downloaded was the 64-bit version.
and It has pre-installed msvc2013_64 at the same path. 
what files should I be looking for here? 
will this work? 

I have downloaded MinGW compiler as well separate from that..

Comment: qmake.exe exists. But I am not sure that g++.exe will exist since now that I see my default compiler is mscv2013_64 . Its quite confusing.

Comment: I am sorry for commenting so much. hehe.

It has clang.exe . will this work?

Comment: @Tedd_Icebeard haha, no problem - was away at lunch. There is only a 32bit mingw on the qt site... not sure if there is a 64 bit version for windows? - it would have to be a standalone version. You can use the MSVC compiler, but.... I really don't like it seems to have some bugs (might be the older versions though).

Comment: The link in the answer is no longer pointing to the correct page, there is no option to download win (mingw)

Answer (score 2):

Well. I was unable to provide the data before but it all makes more sense now. 
What I had installed was Qt for windows 64-bit (vs 2013, 836mb).

Hence, Instead of MinGW, I have msvc2013_64. It does have qmake.exe but doesnt have g++.exe. And I had downloaded it separately.
You're answer was very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, for the MSVC compiler, you need to install that separately by installing MSVC (not free) or MS SDK (free) and then point to it manually.... to be fair Qt normally spots that this is installed once you have installed it (if you do it first). It does not come with the Qt install unlike mingw which does.... so better all around : )

Answer (score 0):

Added MinGW packages to QT installation with the QT Maintenance Tool (C:\Qt\MaintenanceTool.exe)
It allows to add/remove components via the qt repositories. So no need for re-installation.